# React-Leaflet / OpenStreetMap: Detect if the marker is inside a circle

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I have a marker and several zones (Circle). Now I want to detect if the marker is inside a zone. Any idea how I can do this?

data.json

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "longitude": "33.44074300000000",
    "latitude": "-86.78584000000000",
    "exclusionZones": [
      {
        "latitude": "33.42074300000000",
        "longitude": "-86.76584000000000",
        "radius": "350"
      },
      {
        "latitude": "33.52074300000000",
        "longitude": "-86.78984000000000",
        "radius": "500"
      }
    ]
}
```

Map.js
inside MapContainer

```
      {data.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            {data.exclusionZones.map((zone, index) => (
              <Circle
                center={[zone.latitude, zone.longitude]}
                radius={zone.radius}
              />
            ))}
            <Marker
              position={[data.longitude, data.latitude]}
              key={index}           
            >
            </Marker>
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: You can use turf http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains

Comment: The usual approach is to check the distance from the circle's center to the given point. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what Ivan suggested.

```
function isMarkerInCircle(circle, mark) {
  let circleCenter = circle.getLatLng();
  let markerPos = mark.getLatLng();
  return circleCenter.distanceTo(markerPos) < circle.getRadius()
}
```